# C: Cannot get fprintf to print to output-file

Tags: c, printf, fopen

I'm trying to print a matrix into a csv. arg[2] in this is the file name and I can verify that works correctly since it will generate the file but will not populate it. I do close the file and try flushing to it but it does not work.

```
// Open the output/second file and write the contents of truncated DCT matrix into it
outputfp = fopen(argv[2], "w");

if (outputfp == NULL) {

fprintf(stderr, "Can't open output file %s!\n", argv[2]);
exit(1);
                      }
double hold = 0;
printf("test\n");

for (i = 0, i < idx; i++;) {
    for (j = 0, j < ARRAY_WIDTH; j++;) {

    hold = test_write[i][j];

            fprintf(outputfp, "%.61f", hold);
                if (j != ARRAY_WIDTH) {

                    fprintf(outputfp, ",");
                }
                else {
                    //continue;
                }
                fflush(outputfp);
    }
}

fclose (outputfp);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cycle

```
 for (j = 0, j < ARRAY_WIDTH; j++;) {
```

never iterates.

Wrong placement of `,` and `;` makes `j++` the iteration condition. Since before the very first iteration `j++` evaluates to `0`, the cycle is never entered. Apparently, you meant to write

```
 for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_WIDTH; j++) {
```

Comment: Thank you I had an issue earlier where I had incorrectly typed out the for loop I though I had gotten rid of all of them. I just needed a second pair of eyes. I already got it fixed and working. I'm just confused why the compiler views what I had as valid c code.